# jQuery Validate & Nice Select consistent at all?

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-validate

Is Nice Select working with jQuery validate ?
Because I get a strange bug, I'll try to explain it

- Without yet having submitted the form, I'm able to select the the value from nice select plugin and it update correctly the (default select dropdown) value and I can submit the form without problem
- Now if I refresh the page then I submit the form, the jQuery error validate appends as intended because I did not selected some value, so I select some value from (nice select value) and now it doesn't update the (default select) value so I can't submit the form

I thinks that when validate plug-in is called nice select is not dynamically updated, or maybe I miss some thing

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/xws6bbw8/10/)

**html** :

```
<form id="MyForm">
   <select id="MySelect" name="select">
     <option value="">Select a value</option>
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <option value="4">4</option>
   </select>
   <button id="MyButton" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**jQuery** :

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    // Form Validate 
    $('#MyForm').validate({ 
        ignore: [],
        rules: {
            select: {
                selectcheck: true
            }
        }
    });

    jQuery.validator.addMethod('selectcheck', function (value) {
        return (value != '');
    }, "Value required");
    
    // Activate NiceSelect
    $('#MySelect').niceSelect(); 
});
```

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jQuery Validate plugin automatically inserts the validation message after the `select` element.  However in your case, the `select` element is hidden when the Nice Select `div` is dynamically created; the Validate plugin can no longer see or toggle this `label`.

Use [the `errorPlacement` function](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#errorplacement) to place the validation message *after* the Nice Select `div` element.  My custom function is generic and applies to all hidden `select` elements in the form.

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    if (element.is('select:hidden')) {
        error.insertAfter(element.next('.nice-select'));
    } else {
        error.insertAfter(element);
    }        
}
```

However, this answer is not yet complete.  The jQuery Validate plugin normally triggers validation based on the user interacting with the `select` element.  Since your `select` element is hidden and the user is not directly interacting with it, validation is not triggered whenever the Nice Select element is changed.

Use a custom `change` handler function to ensure that the validation message is updated whenever the Nice Select element is changed...

```
$('#MySelect').on('change', function() {
    $(this).valid();
});
```

**Working DEMO:  https://jsfiddle.net/9yvz4ztv/**

---

BTW:  You do not need to write a custom rule to ensure a `select` element contains a value.  Simply use the `required` rule.

```
rules: {
    select: {
        required: true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because of `error` label placement.
The label is placed directly after the `<select>` element, but the plugin uses this code to trigger changes of the `<select>`:

```
// .prev() in this case is the <label class="error">, not "select" ...
n.prev("select").val(s.data("value")).trigger("change")
```

---

You can change the placement of label, using `errorPlacement` option:

```
$('#MyForm').validate({ 
  ignore: [],
  rules: {
    select: {
      selectcheck: true
    }
  },
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    if (element.attr("name") == "select") {
      // place the label after the .nice-select DIV, not <select>:
      error.insertAfter(".nice-select");
    } else {
      error.insertAfter(element);
    }
  }
});
```

[<kbd>JSFiddle demo</kbd>](https://jsfiddle.net/xws6bbw8/12/)