# Add error class to secondary div when first hidden 'select' has error class

Tags: jquery, html, forms, jquery-validate

I am using a form that is being validated with *jQuery Validate*.

When you click the submit button of the form and a required field is left empty, the input box will have an 'error' class added to it.

I have used *Nice Select JS* to custom style my dropdown boxes. It creates a `display:hidden` of the original select and then creates a div of the same list items and then styles it.

When my form is being validated, the error class is being added to the original select in the form, but not the generated div.

The code is as follows:

```
<select id="selector" class="selector error" name="selector" style="display: none;">
    <option value="hide" selected="">RSVP</option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
</select>

<div class="nice-select selector" tabindex="0">
    <span class="current">RSVP</span>
    <ul class="list">
        <li data-value="hide" class="option selected">RSVP</li>
        <li data-value="Yes" class="option">Yes</li>
        <li data-value="No" class="option">No</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My jQuery Validate is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.validator.addMethod('answercheck', function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^\b5\b$/.test(value);
}, "Oops, wrong answer silly");

$.validator.addMethod("valueNotEquals", function(value, element, arg){
  return arg != value;
 }, "Value must not equal arg.");

// validate contact form
$(function() {
    $('#contact').validate({
        ignore: [],
        rules: {
            selector: {
              valueNotEquals: "hide"
            },
            hiddenSelect: {
                required: true,
            },
            name: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            message: {
                required: true
            },
            answer: {
                required: true,
                answercheck: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            selector: {
                valueNotEquals: "Please select an option"
            },
            name: {
                required: "Go on, tell us your name",
                minlength: "Name must consist of at least 2 characters"
            },
            email: {
                required: "No email, no message"
            },
            message: {
                required: "Oops, you have to write something to send this form",
                minlength: "Go on, tell us more"
            },
            answer: {
                required: "Oops, try again"
            }
        },

        errorElement: "span",
        wrapper: "div",  // a wrapper around the error message
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        offset = element.offset();
            error.insertAfter(element)
            error.addClass('message');  // add a class to the wrapper
            error.css('position', 'relative');
            //error.css('left', offset.left + element.outerWidth());
            error.css('bottom', offset.bottom);
        },

        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                type:"POST",
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                url:"php/contact.php",
                    success: function() {
                    $('#success').fadeIn();
                    $(form).fadeOut(500);
                },
                error: function() {
                    $('#error').fadeIn();
                }
            });
        }
    });

    $('select').niceSelect();

  $(".selector").on("click","li",function(){
    $("input[name='hiddenSelect']").val($(this).data("value"));
    var validator = $("#contact").validate();
    validator.form(); 
  });
});
</script>
```

My [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/roxy_p/cngjpuch/1/)

Thanks so much!

Comment: You will have to add the class after your new element has been created https://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Comment: @RafaelDiaz How would I do that for my case?

Comment: You will have to do the validation yourself on code as jQuery Form Validate cannot validate `div`. Have you seen this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37550111/jquery-validate-nice-select-consistent-at-all

Comment: @RafaelDiaz Thanks so much. How do I use the 'add class' script to it though? They suggest `$('#MySelect').on('change', function() {
    $(this).valid();
});` but the article refers to the validation message placement.

Comment: I think that code is what you need, if you want to build your own class (errorClass) to show on validation fail you can try: `$( ".nice-select selector" ).addClass("errorClass");`

Comment: I can't seem to make it work :(

Comment: @roxy-p I edited my answer, added a working demo using the `nice-select`.

Comment: Please show us the relevant jQuery/JavaScript and be more specific about which plugin you are using, because there are many choices.  You've tagged jQuery Validate but this plugin is not named "jQuery Form Validate".

Comment: @Sparky I have now included the jQuery Validate in my original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `highlight` and `unhighlight` callbacks are used for adding/removing classes from all elements being validated.

Use conditional code to check which element is being validated and then add/remove the classes from the Nice Select generated elements.

```
$('#contact').validate({
    ignore: [],
    rules: { ... },
    highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
        // default
        if (element.type === "radio") {
            this.findByName(element.name).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
        } else {
            $(element).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
        }
        // custom
        if (element.name === "selector") {
            $(element).siblings('div.nice-select').addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
        }
    },
    unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
        // default
        if (element.type === "radio") {
            this.findByName(element.name).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
        } else {
            $(element).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
        }
        // custom
        if (element.name === "selector") {
            $(element).siblings('div.nice-select').removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
        }
    },
    // your other options, etc., ....
```

The above is a very crude example to show you the correct approach.  However, it's very specific to an element matching a certain `name`.  If you use Nice Select on more than one element, you may have to adjust your conditional to something more generic.

Comment: This is great! it adds the error class BUT, it doesn't remove the error class when selecting an option?

Comment: @roxy-p, the code depends on the original `select` element being updated immediately by the Nice Select plugin upon a selection.  If that's not happening, you may need to create another handler function.  Create a working jsFiddle demo showing what you have so far, and I can help you with the rest.

Comment: Ok great. Thank you so much! My jsFiddle is (https://jsfiddle.net/roxy_p/cngjpuch/1/)

Comment: @roxy-p, examining your jsFiddle, it appears that the value of the original `select` never changes.  If that's the case, how do you send the selected value when the form is submitted?  In other words, what's the point of Nice Select plugin if you can't send the data?

Comment: @roxy-p, that's really the root problem here.  Most of these jQuery select plugins, Chosen for one example, automatically changes the value of the underlying `select` element.  When that happens, the behavior of the validation plugin follows accordingly.

Comment: I am using a PHP that sends an email with the selected option successfully, but I don't know how to make the script pick up that a selection has been made?

Comment: @roxy-p, how is your server (PHP) picking up the value if the underlying `select` element remains unchanged?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131624/discussion-between-roxy-p-and-sparky).

Comment: is there a way to remove the error as the selection is made and not when the submit button is pressed again?

Comment: @roxy-p, again, this should be happening automatically!  Validation, by default, is triggered every time a new selection is made.  There is something very wrong with the Nice Select plugin as this behavior seems to be flaky and break under certain conditions.

Comment: I removed Nice Select and used Chosen as per your suggestion. It removes the error message, but not the error class when clicking the submit button again

Comment: @roxy-p, Chosen is behaving MUCH better.  Despite the error class, the validation itself is now working.  To fix the classes, simply change the jQuery DOM traversal technique from `.next()` to `.siblings()`...  https://jsfiddle.net/cngjpuch/5/

Comment: This worked amazingly. Thank you so much. So Chosen was the way. Great! :)

Comment: @roxy-p, please accept my answer since I solved all the issues.  Thanks.